# I am having problem with the badge in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';

Badge(
  badgeColor: Colors.black12,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){},
    child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart,
             size: 30,
             color: Colors.white),
  ),
)
```

When I import the package I get an error on child: Badge  and When I don't then I get error on the badgeColor: part. I am stuck on the that for a long long time

I have tried something but as I am new to flutter so I have not that much idea what to do.

Comment: you can use `backgroundColor` from flutter material package.

Answer (score 0):

You can set badge color in badgeStyle properties.

```
Badge(
      onTap: () {},
      badgeStyle: badges.BadgeStyle(
        badgeColor: Colors.black12, // badge color
      ),
      child: InkWell( 
          onTap: (){}, 
          child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
      )
    ),
```

For more badge package information, please read [this](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

Comment: Working great, thanks @Jeff

by the way, can I add a different function in onTap of Inkwell?

Comment: Yes, sure. you can add the function that you want.